# Performing bitwise operations (|, &) on dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, bit-manipulation

In Python

```
0b01 | 0b01 | 0b11
```

results in `3` (which is `0b11`). Assuming that these binary values are in a data frame `df` such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0b10, 0b01, 0b10]})
```

How can I do binary operations on data frames in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy's `bitwise_or.reduce`, AFAIK pandas can't do this on its own.

```
>>> np.bitwise_or.reduce(df.A.values)
3
```